# Symbol's function definition is void: org-mobile-files-alist

Tags: org-mode, mobileorg

EDIT: Now I can see the error only happens if I include certain code to do an automatic push, adopted from https://gist.github.com/3111823. It seems that this block of code wants to use org-mobile-files-alist while it hasn't been initialized, because `'org` is set to have an async loading by default. No matter whether I put the code in `init` or `config` when I require `'org`, it doesn't seem to recognize the variable. Another person seems to be encountering the same error, using the auto-push code below, as seen on github.

Unfortunately if I put the code after `(package-initialize)` it doesn't seem to run at all(i.e. no automatic push no matter what).

The code to do automatic push:

```lisp
  ;; https://gist.github.com/3111823 ASYNC org mobile push...
(require 'gnus-async) 
;; Define a timer variable
(defvar org-mobile-push-timer nil
  "Timer that `org-mobile-push-timer' used to reschedule itself, or nil.")
;; Push to mobile when the idle timer runs out
(defun org-mobile-push-with-delay (secs)
  (when org-mobile-push-timer
    (cancel-timer org-mobile-push-timer))
  (setq org-mobile-push-timer
        (run-with-idle-timer
        (* 1 secs) nil 'org-mobile-push)))
;; After saving files, start an idle timer after which we are going to push 
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 
(lambda () 
  (if (or (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (eq major-mode 'org-agenda-mode))
    (dolist (file (org-mobile-files-alist))
      (if (string= (expand-file-name (car file)) (buffer-file-name))
          (org-mobile-push-with-delay 25)))
    )))
```

The code to initialize org mode asynchronously:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
(require 'org)
(require 'ox)
(require 'ox-beamer)
(require 'ox-latex)
(setq org-export-async-debug nil)
```

I'm new to Emacs and I'm actually using a starter kit called `spacemacs`. So I'm not sure how to fix this problem even after two hours' of trying...

---

I'm seeing the error `Symbol's function definition is void: org-mobile-files-alist` when performing certain operations. Strangely, the error doesn't occur again *after* I execute `org-mobile-push` or `org-mobile-pull` at least once. The nuisance is that it doesn't seem to only influence `org mobile` itself, but also interferes with other functionalities such as archiving. Now whenever I run `C-c C-x C-a` I'll get this error and the entry will *not* be removed from its original `.org` file, **although** it indeed does get archived into the `.org_archive` file. Thus if I try to archive multiple times, the entry gets repeated in the `.org_archive` file but it still remains in the original file. It seems that the process of removing the entry and then saving the file gets interrupted by this error.

An example:

```
Copied: Subtree(s) with 262 characters
Saving file /Users/JX/Dropbox/orgmode/Personal.org_archive...
Wrote /Users/JX/Dropbox/orgmode/Personal.org_archive
let: Symbol's function definition is void: org-mobile-files-alist
```

I already set my `org-mobile-files` variable. However it seems that for some reasons it doesn't get picked up *until* I execute `org-mobile-push` or `org-mobile-pull` manually.

```
org-mobile-directory "/Users/JX/Dropbox/MobileOrg"
org-mobile-files (quote (org-agenda-files))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to `require` the library in which `org-mobile-files-alist` is defined.

The fact that it is defined after you use `org-mobile-push` or `org-mobile-pull` is no doubt because those are autoloaded.  IOW when you try to use them Emacs automatically loads the library that defines them, and that has the result of defining `org-mobile-files-alist` as well.

(If you are using the package system to load such code, instead of, say, putting the code in your `load-path` and using `require`, then be sure you use `package-initialize`.)

Comment: It seems that `org-mobile-files-alist` is defined in `'org` itself as there's no separate `'org-mobile` package... I've located the code that caused the error and tried to move it after `package-initialize`. But doing that makes the code not working at all. Please see my edit. Sorry as I'm new to Emacs and can't really figure out what's going on here...

Comment: You have added a function to `after-save-hook` that references a variable that is not defined when the hook is run. Load `org` before adding that function to the hook. (And I don't think you need both an explicit `require` and a `package-initialize`.) The bottom line is that you need to load Org before you can use this variable.