# Why is calc-precision function definition void?

Tags: calc, require

For a school assignment, we were to find some way to overcome Elisp's limited floating point precision. I found [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Precision), which I thought was pretty useful, but it gives no description of how to actually use it.  I then found [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FloatingPoint#toc3), which says that in order to use calc's arbitrary precision math I need to first set the precision using this:

```
(calc-eval '(calc-precision 20) 'eval)
```

Unfortunately, Emacs then tells me that `calc-precision`'s function definition is void. Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbol's function definition is void: org-mobile-files-alist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/symbols-function-definition-is-void-org-mobile-files-alist)

Answer (score 1):

"function definition is void" most probably means the file where the function is defined has not be loaded yet.  In this case you need to first

> (require 'calc-ext)

Now, how can you find this is `calc-ext`? Just use `calc`, this triggers loading of necessary files, then ask for the docstring of `calc-precision`:

> C-h f calc-precision
>
> calc-precision is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   ‘calc-ext.el’.
>
> (calc-precision N)
>
> Not documented.

By the way, be sure to read section [Precision](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Precision.html#Precision) of calc manual, for the distinction between *precision* and *accuracy*.