# eldoc error: (void-function embark-eldoc-first-target)

Tags: error, eldoc

Linux Mint 20.3

Emacs 27

**For every command** I get the next message in minibuffer:

```
eldoc error: (void-function embark-eldoc-first-target)
```

He my setting of embark package in init.el

```lisp
(use-package embark
  :ensure t
  :bind
  (
   ("M-." . embark-dwim)      ;; good alternative: M-.
   ("C-S-a" . embark-act)
   ("C-h B" . embark-bindings)) ;; alternative for `describe-bindings'
  :init
  ;; Optionally replace the key help with a completing-read interface
  (setq prefix-help-command #'embark-prefix-help-command)
  ;; Show the Embark target at point via Eldoc.  You may adjust the Eldoc
  ;; strategy, if you want to see the documentation from multiple providers.
  (add-hook 'eldoc-documentation-functions #'embark-eldoc-first-target)
  ;; (setq eldoc-documentation-strategy #'eldoc-documentation-compose-eagerly)
  ;; C-x C-h
  (setq prefix-help-command #'embark-prefix-help-command) ;; you can filter
  :config
  ;; Hide the mode line of the Embark live/completions buffers
  (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
               '("\\`\\*Embark Collect \\(Live\\|Completions\\)\\*"
                 nil
                 (window-parameters (mode-line-format . none)))))


;; Consult users will also want the embark-consult package.
(use-package embark-consult
  :ensure t ; only need to install it, embark loads it after consult if found
  :hook
  (embark-collect-mode . consult-preview-at-point-mode))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol's function definition is void: org-mobile-files-alist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12653/symbols-function-definition-is-void-org-mobile-files-alist)

Comment: Search for `void function` and you'll find the same question.

Comment: @Drew In init.el I comment this line and it help.   ;; (setq eldoc-documentation-strategy #'eldoc-documentation-compose-eagerly)

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me if there is anything wrong with that.
But you can definitely avoid the error by placing

`(add-hook 'eldoc-documentation-functions #'embark-eldoc-first-target)`

behind the `config:` keyword instead of the `init:` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that eldoc will call `embark-eldoc-first-target` before embark is loaded (since the `:bind` part of your `use-package` form will defer loading until one of the keys you set is pressed).

Solution: explicitly load `embark` by putting

```
:demand t
```

near the top of the `use-package` form.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't know if this is correct or not, but it looks plausible at first sight.